# Google Play/App Store in-app items, restrict user from buy items

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I dev a game that the users needs to play and raise levels, level 1,2,3,4,5,5,6.

I have multiple items for sell, IAP.

1. at level 1 user can buy 500 coins for 5 dollar.
2. At level 2 user can buy 1000 coins for 5 dollar.
3. At level 3 user can buy 3000 coins for 5 dollar.
4. At level 4 user can buy 7000 coins for 5 dollar.
5. At level 5 user can buy 9000 coins for 5 dollar.

The problem is, if the user just started to play and he is in level 1, he is able to take the SKU of the product number 5, and place an order.

I can nicely "fix" it and show only SKU for the user based on his level, but he is always can decompile my application and search for other SKU.

So, I looking for better way to prevent it,
I thinking about some ideas but I don't know if the can be done using google play.
The main idea is that:

1. user will ask from the game back-end specific item.
2. Backend will check if the level of the user, if the user is level 5 and item number 5 so keep with the purchase process, else, kill the purchase.
3. (User level 5 and want to buy item num 5)The backend will contact with google play, and generate purchase token for specific item number 5.
   4.google play generate token and send it to game backend.
4. backend received the token and forward it to the user.
5. the user will contact google play with the token, pay, and then return to the game.
   7 game backend will check if the purchase is done, and provide the item to the user

So, what basically I tried to describe that I want to approve the SKU before starting purchase process.

Thanks

Comment: `can decompile my application and search for other SKU` does this really make a difference ? how will they buy the other products if the app doesn't allow it ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, The point is that the SKU is registered on google play.. and user is able to directly contact google play and use SKU for the purchase.